# Setting up dual NICs under Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, hyper-v, nic

I'm trying to determine how to set up dual NICs on my Server 2008 box (not R2).  I want all web traffic on one NIC and all Hyper-V traffic on the other.

1. Is this possible?  ( I assume that it is )
2. How is this done?  ( A link to a tutorial you know of would be great )

Both NICs are the same (Intel PRO/1000 EB Network Connection with I/O Acceleration).

Thanks in advance,
Randall

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible & yes it's easy...

Just set the IP address on each nic to be whatever suits and then in the service/application set it to use relevent IP address - Windows will do the rest.

For example:

```
10.0.0.5 Web 
10.0.0.6 Hyper-V
```

In IIS (I presume thats what you are using) set it to listen only on the .5 IP address.  Likewise for Hyper-V.

Comment: What do you mean 'in the service/application set it to use ...' ?

Are you saying there's something in IIS manager that lets me bind the default website to a particular IP address?  What about in the Hyper-V manager?  I see where you can bind the Virtual Network to either card, but only 1 of my NICs shows connected to the internet.

The other simply says Local Only.

Comment: IIS7:  Right click your site and click on "edit bindings" remove the * which means all IP addresses and enter the relevant IP address.

HyperV: - no idea sorry.